# Python 2.7, How to convert (ord>128) string into unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, python-unicode

I am trying to convert a standard string containing >128 chars into Unicode.
For example,

```
a='en métro'
b=u'en métro'
c = whatToDoWith(a)
```

so that I can get c exactly equals to b, in both types and values.

In my real program I got the following error when `txt = 'en métro'`

```
 utxt = txt.decode('utf8')
 File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
 return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

To investigate, I also have the following test code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

c='en métro'
print type(c)
print c
d=c.decode('utf8')
print type(d)
print d
a='中文'
print type(a)
print a
b=a.decode('utf8')
print type(b)
print b
```

and this time result is expected:

```
<type 'str'>
en mÃ©tro
<type 'unicode'>
en métro
<type 'str'>
ä¸­æ–‡
<type 'unicode'>
中文
```

I cannot tell what's the different with my real program.  I also have the 
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line in it.

Can someone point out possible problems?

Answer (score 1):

`str.decode()` should most definitely work in your case:

```
# coding=utf-8

a = "en métro"
b = u"en métro"
c = a.decode("utf-8")

print(type(a))  # <type 'str'>
print(type(b))  # <type 'unicode'>
print(type(c))  # <type 'unicode'>

if b == c:
    print("b equals c!")  # hooray they are equal in value

if type(b) == type(c):
    print("b is the same type as c!")  # hooray they are of equal type
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with different text encodings.

The unicode codepoint 233 (0xe9) is the character LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE.

In UTF-8, this character is encoded to two bytes:

```
>>> unichr(233).encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa9'
>>> for b in unichr(233).encode('utf-8'):print ord(b),
... 
195 169
```

In cp1252 (Windows Western Europe codepage), latin-1 and some other European/latin 8-bit encodings, the character is encoded as a single byte:

```
>>> unichr(233).encode('cp1252')
'\xe9'
>>> ord(_)
233
```